# I get Network Error When Post include cookie in Axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I just made POST request from localhost by sending Cookie as well. I use Axios. I got 405 Method Not Allowed. This my request source code :

```
axios
  .post(
    'http://10.xxx.13.xxx/api/seller/register',
    {
      partner_id: 1,
      mothers_maiden_name: values.mothers_name,
      ktp_url: values.ktp,
      npwp_url: values.npwp,
      verification_photo_url: values.selfie,
      education: parseInt(values.last_education_degree)
    },
    {
      withCredentials: true,
      cookie:
        '_randomName_=5rimcmbr76adhajs2uTvcsG7TOniHpDbkudRd_Z6BvCGME8G5OXG3j-L8b9nMaQdH09XPw__y3noH0KYgFs'
    }
  )
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Success ', response)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error ', error)
  })
```

This is the complete Error message

> OPTIONS http://10.xxx.13.xxx/api/seller/register 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Is there any mistake on my code ? Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not setting the `Cookie` property within the `header` object. Cookies can be set using `axios.post(url, data, headers)` as follows:

```
const data = {
  partner_id: 1,
  mothers_maiden_name: values.mothers_name,
  ktp_url: values.ktp,
  npwp_url: values.npwp,
  verification_photo_url: values.selfie,
  education: parseInt(values.last_education_degree)
};

axios.post('http://10.xxx.13.xxx/api/seller/register', data, {
  headers: {
    withCredentials: true,
    Cookie: '_randomName_=5rimcmbr76adhajs2uTvcsG7TOniHpDbkudRd_Z6BvCGME8G5OXG3j-L8b9nMaQdH09XPw__y3noH0KYgFs'
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log('Success ', response)
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error ', error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to put my own like this for it to work

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  //   withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    withCredentials: true,
  },
});
```

was also getting the network error after adding with